# Problem getting correct parameters for C# P/Invoke call to C++ dll

Tags: c#, pinvoke, oracle-outside-in

Trying to Interop a functionality from the Outside In API from Oracle.
Have the following function:

```
SCCERR EXOpenExport(VTHDOC hDoc, VTDWORD dwOutputId, VTDWORD dwSpecType, 
                    VTLPVOID pSpec, VTDWORD dwFlags, VTSYSPARAM dwReserved,
                    VTLPVOID pCallbackFunc, VTSYSPARAM dwCallbackData, VTLPHEXPORT phExport);
```

From the header files I reduced the parameters to:

```
#define VTVOID void
typedef VTSYSPARAM VTHDOC, VTLPHDOC *;
typedef DWORD_PTR VTSYSPARAM;
typedef unsigned long DWORD_PTR;
typedef unsigned long VTDWORD;
typedef VTVOID* VTLPVOID;
typedef VTHDOC VTHEXPORT, *VTLPEXPORT;
```

These are for 32 bit windows.

Going through the header files, the example programs, and the documentation I found:

1. That `pSpec` could be a pointer to a buffer or `NULL`, so I set it to a `IntPtr.Zero` (documentation).
2. That `dwFlags` and `dwReserved` according to the documentation "Must be set by the developer to 0".
3. That `pCallbackFunc` can be set to `NULL` if I don't want to handle callbacks.
4. That the last two are based on structs that I wrote C# wrappers for using the `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`. Then instatiated an instance and generated the parameters by first creating an `IntPtr` with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(instance))`, then getting the address value which is passed as a `uint` for `dwCallbackData` and a `IntPtr` for `phExport`.

The final parameter list is as follows:

1. `phDoc` as an `IntPtr` which was loaded with an address by the `DAOpenDocument` function called before.
2. `dwOutputId` as `uint` set to `1535` which represents `FI_JPEGFIF`
3. `dwSpecType` as `int` set to `2` which represents `IOTYPE_ANSIPATH`
4. `pSpec` as an `IntPtr.Zero` where the output will be written
5. `dwFlags` as `uint` set to `0` as directed
6. `dwReserved` as `uint` set to `0` as directed
7. `pCallbackFunc` as `IntPtr` set to `NULL` as I will handle results
8. `dwCallBackData` as `uint` the address of a buffer for a struct
9. `phExport` as `IntPtr` to another struct buffer

Still get an undefined error from the API. Meaning that the call returns a 961 which is not defined in any of the header files. In the past I have gotten this when my choice of parameter types are incorrect.

I started out using Interop Assistant which was helpful in learning how many of the parameter types get translated. It is however limited by how well I am able to glean the correct native type from the header files. For example the `hDoc` parameter used in the preceding function was defined as a non-filesytem handle, so attempted to use `Marshal` to create a handle, then used an `IntPtr`, and finally it turned out to be an `int` (actually it was `&phDoc` used here).

So is there a more scientific way of doing this, other than trial and error?

Jim

Comment: Have you tried http://pinvoke.net?

Comment: 961 is 3C1 in hex.  That's defined in sccerr.h as "Access violation"

Answer (score 1):

Your definition:

```
typedef unsigned long DWORD_PTR;
```

Is incorrect — `DWORD_PTR` is defined as:

```
typedef ULONG_PTR DWORD_PTR;
```

Which in turn is defined as:

```
typedef unsigned __int3264 ULONG_PTR;
```

The attribute `__int3264` is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/--int3264), I am reproducing the most important bit:

> The keyword `__int3264` specifies an integral type that has the following properties:
>
> - It is 32-bit on 32-bit platforms
> - It is 64-bit on 64-bit platforms
> - It is 32-bit on the wire for backward compatibility. It gets truncated on the sending side and extended appropriately (signed or unsigned) on the receiving side.

When you are marshaling C "types" such as `DWORD_PTR` whose size depends on the platform pointer size which is often the case with the OS parameters (such as `LPARAM`, `WPARAM`, `LRESULT`, `SIZE_T`, etc) which the name `VTSYSPARAM` appears to suggest, you should use `IntPtr`, not `uint`.

Basically:

> 6. `dwReserved` as `uint` set to `0` as directed

> 8. `dwCallBackData` as `uint` the address of a buffer for a struct

Should be:

> 6. `dwReserved` as `IntPtr` set to `IntPtr.Zero` as directed

> 8. `dwCallBackData` as `IntPtr` the address of a buffer for a struct

Then it should work, and if it doesn't you need to make sure you didn't make a similar mistake when marshaling the necessary structures.

Comment: Why are you answering a 13 year old question? This question is probably severly outdated.

Comment: @JHBonarius
Because the answer marked as correct is not correct and doesn't actually answer the question? Not to mention that the concept of platform pointer length is important to understand for marshaling?

Comment: Th OP has _long_ moved on (maybe even 1-3 employers). and nowadays one would probably use the [Outside-in .NET API](https://docs.oracle.com/outsidein/853/oit/OIPXD/GUID-2DCD158B-5980-4FDE-9359-32B022EB2D38.htm#OIPXD2189). And about specifically specifying type: If you use the source generated [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32), you can even get platform specific types LPARAM, WPARAM, LRESULT, etc generated for you.

Comment: @JHBonarius I didn't answer this because of the OP who might have also died in the meantime -- I answered because the selected answer is a non-answer and should have never been accepted. Your suggestion to use automation and inject another dependency (still in beta at that) in one's project instead of learning how to properly marshal is even worse.